# Checking for number in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
[" 1–4  ": " $10.00 ", " 5–24  ": " $7.20 ", " 25–49  ": " $6.00 ", " 50+  ": " $5.80 "]
```

I need to check the value from an input against this array to get the correct price to compute the total price.

Like so,

```
$('.input-box').change(function(){
    var num = $(this).val();
    if (isInteger(num) ) {

    }
});
```

What are my options with JavaScript?

Comment: your array is invalid, the values need to be comma separated. Colons are used in objects. Do you mean an object instead?

Comment: Or is it an array of objects?

Comment: Do you want to check if the inputed value is in a specific range like `5` to `24` or bigger then `50`, etc. ?

Comment: @Titus Yes, but the values are not static and can change based on the page this code runs on.

Comment: How are ranges represented ? Are these the only constructs `n-n` and `n+` ?

Comment: Correct, I know it can be done but I am at a loss as to the best way

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes you are correct, I did not see that. It was not the source of the issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you seem to have a list of prices associated with different ranges and you want to check what is the price for the value entered by the user (in what range this value falls in).

If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```js
var ranges = {" 1-4  ": " $10.00 ", " 5-24  ": " $7.20 ", " 25-49  ": " $6.00 ", " 50+  ": " $5.80 "}


$("#input-box").change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var price = Object.keys(ranges).reduce((a, c) => {
     var s = c.trim();
     if(/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)){
        var range = s.split("-");
        if(val >= parseInt(range[0]) && val <= parseInt(range[1])){
            a = ranges[c];
        }
     }else{
        s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
        if(val >= s){
            a = ranges[c];
        }
     }
     return a;
  },0);
  $("#price").text(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-box" type="number">
<div>Price <span id="price"></span></div>
```

Comment: the only thing I am seeing on my end is a weird error where when I input 25 it defaults to $10.00

Comment: @Top-Bot I'm not sure what is causing that. I've changed your ranges data to a valid object (`{...}` instead of `[...]`) and replaced the `–` character with `-`. This `–` is not the default line character.

Comment: thanks so much my friend! The - was the problem! It is working correctly now!

Comment: @Top-Bot Great, I'm glad I could help. Good luck.